# A button function in html to change css image tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

To be broad with my question, how can I make a function that will read a value, change the source of an image, then select another value incrementally afterwards? What would be best would be a reference to somewhere that would teach me or if you explain it... My goal usage with this knowledge would be to accomplish this:

[image]This is specific to be and not required but if you could keep in mind my goal with the answer it would helo me out a ton! :D On the left-hand side is the table with textboxes that a user will enter in country names. I want the user to be able to click the button, which reads "Next Speaker", and have a text box be selected and change the value of the textbox underneath the United Nations' Flag to fill in with that country name and also make the flag of that country appear (assuming the flags are all named the identical country name).

```
<img src='flags/(Whatever the selected text box says).svg'>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite easy in Javascript, and requires only a few steps. First, select the image based the id of its containing div:

```
var flagImage = document.querySelector('#flagarea > img');
```

Then, select the input through the same process, and get the name of the currently selected country:

```
var flagSelect = document.querySelector('#flagarea > input');
var currentSelection = flagSelect.value;
```

And finally, change the src attribute:

```
flagImage.src = 'flags/' + currentSelection + '.svg';
```

You tagged this as jQuery, but I would argue it's really no simpler to do this through jQuery than through the basic DOM methods. However, if jQuery is what you want, here's an example of how to do the same:

```
var $flagImage = $('#flagarea > img');
var $flagSelect = $('#flagarea > input');
var currentSelection = $flagSelect.val();
$flagImage.attr('src', 'flags/' + currentSelection + '.svg');
```

You'll want to be sure that all your images have the same aspect ratio, otherwise the layout could change significantly depending on which flag is selected.

Comment: thank you very much! @furkle :D However I am a little confused about which var i should add to the button.... would a function declaration work?

Comment: @SpencerChurchill Sorry, can you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

To change an image source with jquery just use `.attr()`

```
$('img').attr('src', 'newimagesource.jpg');
```

Here is the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: i didn't downvote you and wouldn't - but perhaps it was because this would cause all images on the page to have the src attr changed to be the same by this one line?

Comment: Doesn't matter really one downvote. I just wanted to  know if i didn't read your question correctly. 
About the selector: just adjust it to your needs. For example `$('.my-image-class')` or `$('#my_element_id')`

Comment: sorry - @CarlosCarucce - I am not the OP  - just another forum member who doesn't like unexplained downvotes  :)

Comment: i liked your answer with more information and i actually upvoted to equal it out so no worries